# How to create a VSCode extension for API interaction?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, ui-design

I'm working on a Visual Studio Code extension and want to integrate API interactions similar to the functionality demonstrated in this image:

[image: Example of API interaction within VSCode]

**What I Want to Achieve:**

- Ability to make API requests directly within my VSCode extension.
- Display responses to the user in a similar UI style as the image.

**Background:**

I'm learning how to build VSCode extensions, and I've followed a tutorial that used Postman for API interaction. I'd prefer to have this capability built into my extension.

**What I've Tried:**

- I've researched VSCode extension development, but couldn't find specific guidance on how to achieve this type of integrated API interaction.

**Request for Help:**

Could you please provide:

- Steps or resources on creating this API interaction pattern within a VSCode extension.
- Recommended libraries or modules if needed.

Comment: what tutorial are you following and why does the writer not tell you which extension (s)he uses, the writer is a good source to ask, if you find out will you let us know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an extension called "Thunder Client"